# Left margin on a floating right div

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

Given:

```css
.meta-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 15rem;
}
.outer-div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.inner-div {
  /* padding-left: 20px; */
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta-div">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div">
      111 + 222 + 333 + 444 + 555 + 666 + 777 + 888 + 999
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with a [JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8hLgsp32/).

I am trying to add a `margin-left` to the text and produce the following output:

[image]

I need to have the `float:right` property since  I require the overflowed text to be to the left of the textbox.

I searched online extensively for this problem and found out that one can not add a `margin` property to a floating div, and that I should add to its container instead, but I am just really not sure what trick I could use to mimic the picture above.

I tried creating other sub/outer divs (for the `inner-div` class) and spreading the properties of `float` and `margin-left` across them, I also tried adding some `relative/absolute` properties, but all in vain. I have been stuck on this for 6 hours.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `border-left`:

```css
.meta-div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 15rem;
}
.outer-div {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  border-left:22px solid black;
}

.inner-div {
  /* padding-left: 20px; */
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="meta-div">
  <div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div">
      111 + 222 + 333 + 444 + 555 + 666 + 777 + 888 + 999
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you so much,I will accept the answer in 10 minutes.